# Empty cells turned brown after sort

Tags: excel, formatting

I'm not sure if this is in the right place, apologies if it needs to be moved.

I have a large database - which opened in numbers (Mac), no conditional formatting. When I exported to excel and sorted the data by one of my columns, all of the empty cells turned brown (I've attached a photo). I've also noticed that some of the other cells are the incorrect colour (G is was supposed to denote green and be coloured as such, now it's red).

[image]

Any suggestions as to what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: To be sure - in the original spreadsheet, those empty cells have no fill either, correct? (I'm thinking perhaps it's a Theme change that's changing the colors on you)

Comment: try to re-appy the conditional formatting... it seems like some criteria was set for the brown colour fill..